# how to perform addition n dividison on fetch values through loop in php

Tags: php

hi everyone i fetch the data through for loop now i want to perform addittion n division on ths data as data is fetch in the form of row n each row number are divided and addition by their own parameters how can i defined theses condition in loop for every value
like

```
row1 2  3  4  5  6 

row2 2  4  5  6  7

row3 5  5  6  10  11

row1 2/6  3/6  4/6  5/6 6/6

row2 2/7   4/7  5/7  6/7 7/7
```

code

```
<?php
include('config.php');
$sa="select * from table1 where c13='$d'";
$result=mysql_query($sa) or die(mysql_error());
echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>

</tr>";
$row=array();

while($row[] = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
}
$count = count( $row );
for( $i = 0 ; $i < $count; $i++ ){
    echo $row[ $i ][ 'c1' ];
    echo $row[ $i ][ 'c2' ];
    echo $row[ $i ][ 'c3' ];
    echo $row[ $i ][ 'c4' ];
    echo $row[ $i ][ 'c5' ];
    echo $row[ $i ][ 'c6' ];
    echo $row[ $i ][ 'c7' ];
    echo $row[ $i ][ 'c8' ];
    echo $row[ $i ][ 'c9' ];
    echo $row[ $i ][ 'c10' ];
    echo $row[ $i ][ 'c11' ];
    echo $row[ $i ][ 'c12' ];
}
```

plz help me in ths

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do something like this: 
`$row[$i]/12 + 2`

I'm not sure what do you mean by dividing and adding according to their own parameters?

Comment: sir see my row own paramenter means that element of first row divided by their element on fourh column n elements of second row divided by their own element of second row